# How to send file and data using requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send a python file and some json data to the server via python requests module. Below is the snippet of my code.

```
files = {'file': (FILE, open('test_hello.py', 'rb'), 'text/plain')}
job_data = dict(name='nice', interval=50, script_path="crap")
r = post(url=url, data=job_data, files=files)

r.status_code
400

r.text
u'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>\n'
```

I am getting status code 400. Can someone please point out what am I missing here ? Or share a correct code snippet ?

**PS**: I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow but they all give the same error code. I have tried them.

**NOTE:** I am using Flask 0.10 on server side

**UPDATE:** The client-side code was working fine. **It was my server side Flask code which was bad.** It even gave an error message saying "Bad Request"

```
r.text
400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.'
```

This error message made me think that client side code is not working as expected even though its looks good and is similar to other stackoverflow questions I have tried.

Thanks to all for responding to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as written when I POST to httpbin. Whatever service you are sending data too is expecting something else though so without knowing what it is expecting, we cannot help further.

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': ('test_hello.py', open('test_hello.py', 'rb'), 'text/plain')}
>>> job_data = dict(name='nice', interval=50, script_path="crap")
>>> r = requests.post(url=url, data=job_data, files=files)
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.json()
{u'files': {u'file': u"print 'hi'\n"}, u'origin': u'208.91.164.254', u'form': {u'script_path': u'crap', u'interval': u'50', u'name': u'nice'}, u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/post', u'args': {}, u'headers': {u'Content-Length': u'462', u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate', u'Accept': u'*/*', u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.8.1', u'Host': u'httpbin.org', u'Content-Type': u'multipart/form-data; boundary=8064073dc3f1449cb3e46a7a6c5669a3'}, u'json': None, u'data': u''}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this troubleshooting technique. I realized my client side code was working. It was my server side ERROR msg that mislead me.

Answer (score 1):

A 400 means that the request was malformed. The data stream sent by you to the server didn't follow the rules, it expects data of a certain type (say JSON) but the type of object that you're sending is a . They both are different and check out python's [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)  and use them in future while dealing with JSON objects

Answer (score 0):

Using data as a parameter sends it as a form-encoded data not as json unless suitable encoded. `json.dumps(data)` is typically used to encode python data as json but recent versions of [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) have json handling built in.

```
r = post(url=url, json=job_data, files=files)
```

will send job_data to the server as a json encoded string.